# Testing an index in a for loop - Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Very simple problem, although I am having quite a tough time solving it.

Take a look at the code and I will explain below:

```
def printc(some_text):
    split_text = list(some_text)

    for x in split_text:
        if x is '{'
            # this is what i need help with


printc("{CCyan, {RRed, {YYello)
```

The idea behind this and it is still very early in the code development, but what I am trying to do is create an iterator that searches through "split_text" and finds the character '{' then i want to test what character is situated right next to it. How would i go about doing that?

For example is searches through split_text and finds the first { i want to see if the character next to it is either A, B, C, etc...

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want expected the function to print `C`, `R`, and `Y` if the input is `"{CCyan, {RRed, {YYello"` ?

Comment: Take a look at `enumerate`

Comment: also, you shouldn't be using `is` here. read up on the difference between `==` and `is`, it's important

Comment: @acushner i def will do that, i always thought it was shorthand for the same thing to make it more 'pseudo-code'

Comment: what's the real problem you are trying to solve? also, strings are already a list.. you don't need to create a list out of it.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman I find it easier to split up a string into individual characters, mess with them as I see fit and splice them back together. May not be the best way, but it works for me so far.

Comment: nope, it compares objects' identities, not their values.

Comment: @pypy, regarding a list of characters, did you know that `for x in some_text` gives the same result as `for x in list(some_text)` minus creating a completely unnecessary list?

Answer (score 4):

Much easier with a single regex.

```
import re
re.findall('{(.)', some_text)
```

outputs:

```
['C', 'R', 'Y']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for x, y in zip(some_text, some_text[1:]):
    if x == '{':
        print y
```

you could even make it simpler:

```
chars = [y for (x, y) in zip(some_text, some_text[1:]) if x == '{']
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually iterate in pairs if I need something like this:

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    """Iterate in pairs

    >>> list(pairwise([0, 1, 2, 3]))
    [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
    >>> tuple(pairwise([])) == tuple(pairwise('x')) == ()
    True
    """
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

Usage is like:

```
for left, right in pairwise(iterable):
    ...
```